# image not displaying when uploading in php

Tags: php, html

I'm using a very simple php page to upload a file and display the image to same page; however, the image is not displaying. I checked whether the image was being uploaded and where, and it is being uploaded to the same directory as the php file.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>File Upload</h1>
    <form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select File: <input type="file" name="filename" size="10" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="upload" />
    </form>

    <?php
        //checking if user uploaded image
        if($_FILES) {
            $name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $name);
            echo "Uploaded image $name <br/>";
            echo "<img scr='$name' height='100px' width='100px'/>";
        }
    ?>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: remove px from height and width attributes (default pixel). (this is just a suggestion)

Comment: provide it http path with image name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "<img scr='$name' height='100px' width='100px'/>";
```

change to :

```
echo "<img src='{$name}' height='100px' width='100px'/>";
```

*edit:* Use curly brackets when including a variable in double quotes.

And please provide whole path of the image, like `http://www.example.com/path/to/image/image.png`

Answer (score 1):

1. Please check your upload.php
2. Write code as shown below.

> `echo "<img src='" . $name . "' />`";

when you write php variable in html ...you should concatenate that variable with .

Comment: You need to change to : `echo "<img src='" . $name . "' />";`, just need to add single quotes for `src attribute`, otherwise everything is fine (y) :)